# Same file same name moved one is lost how should I get lost file

Tags: windows

1. I inserted my 2GB memory card into my PC.
2. After that I moved all the files to my desktop.
3. After moving all the file I ejected the memory card.
4. Again another 8GB memory card I inserted to my OC.
5. I moved all the files to the desktop without making a folder, I just moved, and was prompted to select replace the file etc.
6. I simply select replace after that I ejected my memory card.
7. I search on desktop moving file, I only see the 2GB file moved, the 8GB file has been lost.

How can I recover the lost file on my PC?

Comment: It's probably lost forever. Protip, don't move photos like that next time. The image numbers conflict all the time, even when they're not the same photos.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrote it, so it is gone. You can try to check the waste basket, if it is there, you can just recover it from there; otherwise, it will be difficult.

If you didn't use the computer after that, you can try 'undelete' software, and it may be able to reconstruct the content.

Basically, you told the system that this space is now 'unused', and the system will overwrite it when it needs space for something. Chances are that the OS does not reuse this space directly, but uses other space first; that depends on the fill grade of your hard disk and many other details.

Definitely do not use the computer, until you have recovery software ready and know how to use it. Otherwise, *any* activity increases the chance of the content being permanently destroyed.